# sql injection query error in bwapp?

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I am getting this error in mysql Server version: 5.0.96-0ubuntu3 -

```
Error SQL query: Documentation

SELECT * FROM bWAPP.movies UNION ALL SELECT 1 , 2, 3, schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata, 6, 7, 7; LIMIT 0 , 30

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '6 , 7 , 7  LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

the bWAPP.movies has following structure-

```
id  int(10)                 
title   varchar(100)    
release_year    varchar(100)    
genre   varchar(64) 
main_character  varchar(100)    
imdb    varchar(100)    utf8_general_ci     
tickets_stock   int(10)
```

and information_schema.schemata has this-

```
CATALOG_NAME            varchar(512)    
SCHEMA_NAME         varchar(64) 
DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME  varchar(64) 
DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME      varchar(64) 
SQL_PATH
```

I have tried two query -
**the correct one is -**

```
SELECT * FROM bWAPP.movies UNION ALL SELECT 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata; LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**and the one giving error is -**

```
SELECT * FROM bWAPP.movies UNION ALL SELECT 1 , 2, 3, schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata, 6, 7, 7; LIMIT 0 , 30
```

why the second one is giving error and not the 1st one ?